# Need help with MacBook Pro rebooting after upgrade to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

My mid-2010 MacBook Pro keeps rebooting after upgrade to Mountain Lion.

The crashes are happening in different applications but seems to happen most often when scrolling inside of an email or Safari, opening iPhoto, or opening a video from Youtube.

Not sure who can review the panic report and offer assistance.

> Thu Sep 13 12:30:25 2012 panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff7f9bf61c85):
>   NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
>   0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80baab7000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4
>   Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff80973ab040 :
>   0xffffff801b81d5f6  0xffffff80973ab0b0 : 0xffffff7f9bf61c85 
>   0xffffff80973ab140 : 0xffffff7f9c05b5b7  0xffffff80973ab1a0 :
>   0xffffff7f9c05b62b  0xffffff80973ab210 : 0xffffff7f9c370883 
>   0xffffff80973ab350 : 0xffffff7f9c08175d  0xffffff80973ab380 :
>   0xffffff7f9bf6b9e6  0xffffff80973ab430 : 0xffffff7f9bf670b8 
>   0xffffff80973ab620 : 0xffffff7f9bf67b3a  0xffffff80973ab710 :
>   0xffffff7f9cfd2c51  0xffffff80973ab760 : 0xffffff7f9cfcffad 
>   0xffffff80973ab7a0 : 0xffffff7f9cfce1a5  0xffffff80973ab7d0 :
>   0xffffff7f9cf7efef  0xffffff80973ab7f0 : 0xffffff7f9cf9a94c 
>   0xffffff80973ab820 : 0xffffff7f9cf9a6f3  0xffffff80973ab870 :
>   0xffffff7f9cf990f1  0xffffff80973ab890 : 0xffffff7f9cf87e98 
>   0xffffff80973ab8c0 : 0xffffff7f9cfcbd54  0xffffff80973ab900 :
>   0xffffff7f9cf86f31  0xffffff80973aba80 : 0xffffff7f9cfc82ee 
>   0xffffff80973abb40 : 0xffffff7f9cf85a3a  0xffffff80973abba0 :
>   0xffffff801bc64929  0xffffff80973abbc0 : 0xffffff801bc65ed0 
>   0xffffff80973abc20 : 0xffffff801bc638ef  0xffffff80973abd70 :
>   0xffffff801b8981a1  0xffffff80973abe80 : 0xffffff801b820abd 
>   0xffffff80973abeb0 : 0xffffff801b810448  0xffffff80973abf00 :
>   0xffffff801b8195fb  0xffffff80973abf70 : 0xffffff801b8a5ad6 
>   0xffffff80973abfb0 : 0xffffff801b8ced13 
>         Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
>            com.apple.NVDAResman(8.0)[6A699209-FB98-316B-A3C0-DCA82AA8C86B]@0xffffff7f9befa000->0xffffff7f9c1fcfff
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[8C9E06A4-13D0-33F5-A377-9E36F0ECC229]@0xffffff7f9be6f000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[E37F420A-B5CD-38ED-9441-5247583B6ACE]@0xffffff7f9bee6000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[5D671681-D21B-3CCA-9810-B15E648C1B27]@0xffffff7f9bea3000
>            com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(8.0)[9CD95A4A-FD94-349E-A4B6-FC3B74E197F5]@0xffffff7f9c20a000->0xffffff7f9c52cfff
>               dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.0.0)[6A699209-FB98-316B-A3C0-DCA82AA8C86B]@0xffffff7f9befa000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[8C9E06A4-13D0-33F5-A377-9E36F0ECC229]@0xffffff7f9be6f000
>            com.apple.GeForce(8.0)[91C40470-82BA-329A-A9D7-4C70F28275FD]@0xffffff7f9cf79000->0xffffff7f9d03bfff
>               dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(8.0.0)[6A699209-FB98-316B-A3C0-DCA82AA8C86B]@0xffffff7f9befa000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[E37F420A-B5CD-38ED-9441-5247583B6ACE]@0xffffff7f9bee6000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[8C9E06A4-13D0-33F5-A377-9E36F0ECC229]@0xffffff7f9be6f000
>               dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[5D671681-D21B-3CCA-9810-B15E648C1B27]@0xffffff7f9bea3000
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WebProcess
>
> Mac OS version: 12B19
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 12.1.0: Tue Aug 14 13:29:55 PDT
>   2012; root:xnu-2050.9.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   3005059E-270B-3B9F-940D-7A66C05DDC9D Kernel slide:
>   0x000000001b600000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff801b800000 System model
>   name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 2564255630731 last loaded kext at
>   32532016903: com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction 97 (addr
>   0xffffff7f9db99000, size 16384) last unloaded kext at 155001924757:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI 5.1.5 (addr 0xffffff7f9c7dc000, size
>   65536) loaded kexts: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelProfile   97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
>   com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.0.9f8
>   com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.12.69
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver  122
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.3.0f2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.3.0f2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.5.10
>   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport    4.0.9f8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.6.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.0.33
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl   3.2.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics 8.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl  3.2.6 com.apple.GeForce 8.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.2d0
>   com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB   8.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor  3.0.2d6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    235.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   3.1.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    320.15
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard   235.4
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.BootCache   34 com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient   3.5.1
>   com.apple.driver.XsanFilter   404 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.6
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 601.15.21
>   com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet  3.2.5b3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI  4.9.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    2.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 5.1.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    1.6.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 1.6 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  1.6 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient   196.0.0
>   com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 4.0.39
>   com.apple.security.quarantine 2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 196.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction  97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction 97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction  97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction    97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction 97
>   com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction  97
>   com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily    97 com.apple.kext.triggers  1.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib   2.3.0f2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.8.9fc9
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.6
>   com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport   4.0.9f8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.10d0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.10d0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 86.0.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.0.9f8
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP  2.2.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   2.3.0f2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   2.3.0f2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.2.6
>   com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal  8.0.0 com.apple.NVDAResman  8.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.4
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy   1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.2.0d16
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.3.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.3d11
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.5.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.5.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch   235.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    5.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 5.1.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    5.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    3.5.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.7.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.5.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.5.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   5.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 500.15
>   com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController   1.0.2b1
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily  4.5.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   5.1.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  1.6.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily   1.8.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1
>   com.apple.security.sandbox    220 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    7 com.apple.driver.DiskImages   344
>   com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily   1.8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    28.18
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    1.6 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

Comment: You are not alone. I am in the same boat.

Comment: I have the same issue! I found your thread on google by searching by "91C40470-82BA-329A-A9D7-4C70F28275FD", wonder what it is. Have you discovered anything else regarding our problem? please keep the question thread up to date! :)

Comment: Does the problem still occur after you install the 10.8.2 Mountain Lion update?

Comment: If you have 5 to 10 instanced of this happening - it would be pretty easy to look over the logs and see what might be causing the panic. Are you looking for a canonical article on how to debug kernel panics? Apple is the holder of the source code to the browser and the OS - so the "canonical" solution is to file a bug report with them and/or isolate the issue by reinstalling the OS and not installing plug in / third party software if that is contributing to the issue. The _big_ question, is can you reproduce the panic and make it happen within 5 minutes of trying to cause a crash?

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same kernel panic on my mid-2010 MBP. It took me a few months to get around to upgrading to Mountain Lion but now this is driving me crazy. I'm on 10.8.2. Has anybody found a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

From the log above, it seems like it's graphics related. There is also a thread on Apple's community forums confirming that suspicion.

It looks like the graphics chip is not functioning as intended. They suggested looking into getting it replaced. I know this is not an immediate solution, but I hope it narrows down the issue further.

Comment: As a kernel developer, I would agree with that assessment. :-) It makes sense that this happens in Safari and iPhoto, as those are known to use GPU acceleration. I assume all firmware and OSX updates have been installed; if so, the hardware is likely defective.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to agree with @Melwan; however, I know how Apple Techs work and they're going to push you to attempt a clean install before diagnosing your hardware. So go ahead and do a clean install (Back up your files of course) then boot your mac holding down the alt key, you should see your HD show up and a restore partition show up. Select the restore partition and make sure you wipe the harddrive and do a clean install. This may help if something that handles your graphics installed wrong. It's worth a shot, especially if you don't have AppleCare any longer.